# Terrible NAA handling came up in audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, not-an-answer, specific-answer

[This audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6867856) is a great example of what not to flag as NAA, since it really has a decent chance of being some sort of answer. (I don't know if it's correct, of course, but it even has a passing relation to the problem at hand.)

I cannot reverse the unfortunate audit candidacy myself, so I figured I'd post this here, as it's worse than most I see.

Comment: Agreed. The author really shouldn't of said "I had a similar problem", which is really close to "I *have* a similar problem".

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Right, and I've started editing posts to remove that sort of NAA-bait whenever I see it. Anything we can do about those trigger-happy flaggers, though?

Comment: Aside from better reviewers, nothing I can think of. Voted to undelete btw. That *may* take it off the audit list.

Comment: It was likely flagged because it **is** a completely wrong and irrelevant answer that a new user decided to throw onto some old question because they hit the phrase "line breaks html" or something. It seems pretty clear to me that they didn't read the question or attempt to understand what it was even asking about. Funnily, most of the other answers there are blatantly wrong too.

Comment: @animuson Its always been the policy that "Wrong answers are still answers" though. Most of the other answers even use HTML (which may be wrong as you pointed out, I'm no expert in that).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Imho, that answer *should* be deleted. it's worthless noise and doesn't belong there. The fact that there's a helpful flag on it is unfortunate. They really should let us clear flags that get used for audit cases without having to undelete truly terrible content.

Comment: @animuson Agree with that. I don't have a problem with it being deleted, so much as it being deleted *for that reason*.

Comment: Unfortunately with the current system, "for what reason" doesn't matter. The system only cares that it is a) deleted and b) has a helpful flag on it. It should be deleted, but it should not have a helpful flag on it, and I don't like having to settle for not doing (A) because we can't fix (B), which is why I didn't undelete it.

Comment: "Terrible handling"... "great example"... seriously? I don't see what's the big deal is. The difference between NAA and VLQ has been diminishing over time, and by now is almost nonexistent -- most of these flags are handled by reviewers who **don't know** whether the post was flagged VLQ or NAA. Reviewers are simply to decide: should it stay or should it go, for whatever reason.  Only moderators can see what the flag was, but they are not shown these flags until an hour passes.

Answer (score 11):

It's not [not an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

However, it *is* very low quality. The answerer clearly either failed to read the question or badly misunderstood it, but even apart from that this answer fails the smell test: it's the equivalent of searching for instructions on replacing your car's disc brakes and finding the answer, "I was having a similar problem and used a hammer".

[image]

Which is why it was flagged as Very Low Quality and then deleted. And why it's now being used as an audit.